# prop() and attr() do not work in IE11?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<button id='stop' onclick='Stop()'>Stop</button>
<button id='play' onclick='Play()' disabled>Play</button>
```

and:

```
function Stop() {
    alert('Stop is clicked');
    $('#play').prop('disabled', false);   $('#stop').prop('disabled', true);
}

function Play() {
    alert('Play is clicked');
    $('#stop').prop('disabled', false);   $('#play').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Simple enough.  It works fine in Chrome.  But the disabling part does not work in IE11.  I tried using `.attr('disabled','disabled')` and also that does not work in IE.  Is this a known problem and what's the workaround?

PS: I am using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: looked fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g8V7S/1/

Comment: Thanks, but the jsfiddle still does not work for me.  The Stop/Play buttons disabled state should be swopped every time a button is clicked.

Comment: IE 11 in Windows 8.1.  The exact same page works fine in Chrome on the same PC or via an Android phone browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found this issues right now... jQuery’s `attr()` method doesn’t seem to work on IE11 (at least).
In my case, I tried to use `attr('value')` with no luck. Instead, I had to use `val()`.

In you case, you should probably use `$(<your-element>).is(":disabled")`.

Comment: This unfortunately won't address the actual issue, which is being able to toggle the disable property of the elements - the `is("..."')` functionality is only a read